# sortable.create: option "dropOnEmpty" not working inside a table with tbody element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drag-and-drop, scriptaculous

I am trying to implement drag and drop functionality using "sortable.create" among 4 tables. The drag and drop functionality is working perfectly fine but is a particular table is empty then I am not able to drop anything inside it even after providing the option "dropOnEmpty: true".

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

If it's the same as what I've experienced, the problem is due to the empty element not having any height. I use ULs when sorting, but I'd bet TABLE is similar. Try:

`table.sortable {min-height:100px;}`

...or similar dimension that fits your formatting (and class names). You can also have your controller supply a dummy entry for when there are none to sort for that table, to give it some height.